# How to read .array file and transfer the numbers into an empty list in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to extract the numbers from a file named `sample.array` into an empty list in Python.

I have tried the usual way to read the file, but it turns out that I got nothing.

Below is my code and a picture of the `sample.array`:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

def read_file(filename):
    """
    Your file will need to extract numbers from an array and 
    """
    list_of_numbers = []
    file = open(sys.argv[1]).readline()
    for number in file:
        list_of_numbers.append(number)

print(list_of_numbers)
```

[image: Sample array]

Comment: Please do not show your example data as a graphic. Copy-and-paste or type it into your question, so we can copy-and-paste into our editors and see how to help you. Also explain the assumptions we can make on the structure of the data in the file--one example could result from many different formats.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I haven't became this familiar with this website. The file is just 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. and this is an .array file.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Read the file as a single string (Google it!)
2. Then split the string. (Google this too!).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert str to int too.

```
def read_file(filename):
    list_of_numbers = []
    # do you want parse filename arg from command line or just as arg?
    # sys.argv[1] - use it instead of filename if your script get args from command line
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            list_of_numbers += list(map(int, line.split()))
    return list_of_numbers


nums = read_file("file.txt");
print(nums)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not in an environment to test code right now, but this should do the work

```
file = open(“sampleArray.txt”, “r”) 
list_of_numbers = file.split(" ")
print(list_of_numbers)
```